# Macbook pro m1 selenium starting tests in intel chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I have a macbook pro m1 series macbook.

I'm running selenium tests via Intellij.I found that my tests were very slow when I used the chorome driver while doing my tests.After a long research, the problem is that my macbook with apple slicon processor is running chorome with intel driver.That's why my tests are so slow.how can i fix this problem.

I deleted and installed Chrome, I did a lot of research, but I couldn't find a complete solution.

Comment: Happening in many of our colleague's system too. As of now the workaround is downgrading the Chrome version. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4456

Also there is no update on the fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by downloading JDK from [here](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11) and use it in intellij for my selenium project with chromedriver [MAC_OS_ARM64 Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip) or you can use [bonigarcia library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/5.1.0) and use below two lines:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: any idea on why its the case? Whats wrong with  other Open JDKs such as Correta?

Comment: m1 need to run aarch64 java .....or else it will run your java in rosetta emulation which is basically running intel support softwares..so because of translations and all it takes time. You can check in activity monitor ....along side ur application u will see a kind column if it shows intel then it is doing emulation and that makes it slow.

Answer (score 0):

I updated from OpenJDK 11 to Amazon Corretto-11 for my project and now my selenium tests are running blazing fast when before they were running at half the speed of smell.